# batch servlet requests in appengine

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to combine all requests received in a period (say, 1 second) and serve them in a batch.

Basically, I am looking for a way to handle a list of 'http servlet request response' maps, instead of serving each and every req-resp pair separately. I hope, HttpServletReqRespMapList abstraction could share common state and it would be useful in appengine environment.

Please share, any ideas, or known implementations, ideal way to implement this in google appengine environment.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to implement some caching using such mapping and reduce cost. If ti is true than you should look to other approaches.

1. You can use DataStore or even MemCache to cache preprocessed data based on request parameters.
2. You can try to use static files uploaded as a part of your WAR file. Static files do not require any CPU time so it is a best way to reduce costs.

Batch processing is not natural for Java Web application. Usually the problem could be solved in another way.

If you need common state between requests than problem becomes more complex. AppEngine architecture is based on instance-on-demand concept. So you do not have any guaranty which instance will process your request. And this mean that you can not have shared static data. So the state could be shared only using some persistent storage like DataStore/MemCache or even some FileService. But be careful when you use it, because you must consider latency of each technology.

The last reason for such architecture I see is some workflow you need to implement based on requests received. If you need some workflow you should take a look to http://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/ which allow to have execution flow control for Task API.

Comment: as I have very few things to share among very large number of client requests (like, a share ticker, or game state), I was looking for such abstraction.

Comment: Than you need yo use datastore and memcache to speed up process

Comment: Thanks, may be I am trying to over-optimize, that could lead me nowhere. I will try to stick to basics, and proceed for now.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not, and the servlet standard doesn't provide any mechanism for this in any case.

Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I have similar things to share among multiple clients / requests; like, a game state to share among players and viewers.